# How to check two values are present in two columns or not in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 columns on a `chat` table where `id` is an auto increment primary key, and `sender_id` and `receiver_id` are not null integers.

```
id sender_id receiver_id
1  1992      1332
2  1922      1232
3  1232      1211
4  1922      1211
5  1211      1922
6  1922      1211
7  1232      1211
8  1211      1922
```

Now, I want to get exact `id` values where `1922` and `1211` are talking to each other as sender or receiver.

I tried:

```
select * from chat where sender_id OR receiver_id= 1922
```

This is giving me where `1922` is present in either of columns but I don't understand how to check if two values present in one row or not!

The expected output I need from the query are the `ids`: `4,5,6,8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a query with multiple conditions on the `WHERE` clause. Basically you want a condition where:

```
(sender_id = X AND receiver_id = Y) OR (sender_id = Y AND receiver_id = X)
```

The query could be like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    chat
WHERE
    (sender_id = 1922 AND receiver_id = 1211)
OR
    (sender_id = 1211 AND receiver_id = 1922)
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can do:

```
select * 
from chat 
where (sender_id = 1922 OR sender_id = 1211) OR (receiver_id= 1922 OR receiver_id = 1211)
```

or:

```
select * 
from chat 
where sender_id IN (1922,1211) OR receiver_id IN (1922,1211)
```

Comment: No. Not quite what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I guess I mean the difference between your query and the accepted answer